# Get string after second instance of a character

Tags: php

I have the string 'sn 123456 dead blah de blah de blah' and I would like to be able to single out the remainder of the string after the second instance of a space.  What is the best way to do this using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PHP: Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) like the following

```
 $str = 'sn 123456 dead';
 $strarr = explode(" ", $str, 3);
 echo $strarr[2];
```

Comment: Sorry, I have made the question clearer, it is the remainder of the string after the second space I need, not just the 3 word.

Comment: @tatty27 Please let us know if the updated answer worked for you, So others who see this question will be benefitted.

Comment: I am currently working on it, as soon as it is working I will

Comment: No Problem Thanks :)